# Confused when to use Adapters and which one?

Tags: android

I have read a little bit about ListAdapter - ArrayAdapter - BaseAdapter - CursorAdapter. I don’t understand there usage in true sense.

I have scenario, in which I am showing word in a TextView and then there are 4 radio button options and user will select one.

I am confused if I can use any adapter functionality. Like when the word on the top is move to next word. Meaning selection shown as radio button options updates automatically because of binding.

In a nut shell i am looking for something like auto binding in .NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ArrayAdapter` can be used to link say a list of items with an array. The `ArrayAdapter` works between an your array data and a list item layout to populate a list.

a `CursorAdapter` can work in a similar way but can link a database query result set (in a cursor) to a list by populating list items.

They are both subclasses of [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html)

If data changes in either the database tables or Array both the Array and Cursor Adapters can be refreshed via `notifyDataSetChanged()`

Answer (score 1):

BaseAdapter is the most basic Adapter of ListView. All remaining adapters extend from BaseAdapter.

If you are confused which adapter is suitable for you scenario, let choose BaseAdapter first.

Comment: Just to be clear , Adapters are only used with ListView. Correct ?